# Calling the date time , without initiating the dialog box of Datetime control

Tags: android

I am basically using a datetime control in my application.

Wherein on a click event i am initiating datetime dialog.

In another scenario, i want to move current date, to next day, or previous day.
I don't want the dialogbox of date time control to be displayed.

Is it possible??

Answer (score 0):

The DatePicker and TimePicker controls are available as widgets for you to use in your layouts or code.

You can then build the next day / previous day functionality yourself by setting the date / time of those controls.